# Need hotkey/button to comment out a block of code in Visual Studio 2008 Express

Tags: visual-studio-express

I'm coming from Eclipse, working in Visual Studio 2008 Express and just want to highlight code, right-click and comment it out.

- nothing in right-click
- looking in Tools | Options, Toolbars, Commands, can't find a button for it...

How do I activate this the comment/uncomment feature, I know Visual Studio 2003 had it.

HERE ARE THE ANSWERS, TURNS OUT IT DEPENDS WHAT YOU ARE USING:

**Visual Studio 2008 Full Version:**

Comment    <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>K</kbd> , <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>
Uncomment  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>K</kbd> , <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>U</kbd>

**Visual Web Developer 2008 Express:**

Comment    <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>K</kbd> , <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>
Uncomment  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>K</kbd> , <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>U</kbd>

**Visual C# 2008 Express:**

Comment    <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd> , <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>
Uncomment  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd> , <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>U</kbd>

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Weird it's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>C</kbd> (Comment) and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>U</kbd> (Uncomment)

[image]

Normally It's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>U</kbd> as Mauro says. Express Edition default (and only) keyboard mapping says otherwise.

Answer (score 11):

the key combination

Comment    <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>K</kbd> , <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>
Uncomment  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>K</kbd> , <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>U</kbd>

That's VS 2008, not sure if the express editions have the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

Mauro is right about the shortcuts, they're in Express as well.  You can also get to the Comment/Uncomment block commands in the Edit->Advanced menu.  You probably also have a toolbar icon to do this that looks like a couple of lines, with a few indented blue ones.

Answer (score 3):

Visual Assist X also has better shortcuts for this:

> `/` - comment the block with `//`
>   `*` - comment the block with `/* */`

I'm not sure if it Visual Assist works with The express edition though